# OS X Lion multiple Spaces annoyance

Tags: macos, spaces

I like to set my desktops a certain way for work.

I noticed that when I command-tab around my Spaces, it seems to switch around the order of desktops when I access with ctrl+arrow.

This is really annoying. **For example** I set my two terminal and coding/debugger screens to be adjacent, then I alt-tab to my email and all of a sudden the email screen is sitting between my two work screens.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try checking the obvious?[image: Did you try checking the obvious?]